# Azure - How do I deploy needed DLLs when deploying via github

Tags: azure, github, kudu

I have continuous deployment to Azure via GitHub "working". It detects pushes, grabs and builds the code. All great.

BUT, I've had to add a DLL (one of ours) to the repo, so that it gets deployed too.

I'd *really* like to not have the DLL in the repo. So how can I get the Kudu deployment engine (or anything else) get the DLL from some place (where?).

Comment: if your concern is privacy - then you private github repository. Or just deployment from **local** git repository and keep your DLLs in your local git repository (with the whole project). You cannot use multiple deployment sources for a single project.

Comment: My concern is not privacy. 
I think it's bad practice to have binaries in git - and I'd end up with those binaries in several repos, since I have several services all of which use the same data access DLL's - the code of which is in it's own repo.

Comment: then pack your binaries as NuGet packages and let the CI server restore them from NuGet. You can even instruct the Azure Web Apps deployment environment (a.k.a. Kudu) to restore packages from private NuGet repository. After all, NuGet is the official Microsoft way of distributing binaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, committing binaries to git is bad practice. Instead, the widely accepted practice is to rely on NuGet packages which are retrieved during deployment. If your packages are not of general use, you can create your own myget feed to keep them off nuget.org.